# Change bash_profile to different file path

Tags: macos, unix, bash

Is there a way to change the file that my terminal loads so that it never opens or executes my .bash_profile? But still executes a different file in a different directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest thing to do would be to change the contents for your `.bash_profile` file to contain only:

```
. /path/to/other/file
```

Comment: I am looking for a way for the bypass the bash_profile so that no code could be inserted into the file.

Answer (score 2):

You can inhibit reading *any* default startup file with `--noprofile --norc`. Additionally you can give bash the location of *one* startup file using `--rcfile file`. See `man bash` for details about these options.

In the file provided by `--rcfile` you can load the standard files in any way you wish.

But the consequences are, that you have to emulate quite a bit of code to get the behaviour of that shell approximately right in regard to system settings, aliases, completions, standard functions, ... You must be *very* desperate to go that road.

Answer (score 1):

No - you can pass --noprofile to bash to inhibit reading the .bash_profile file completely, but you can't override the location of the file bash looks for.

From `man bash`:

> When  bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a
>   non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and
>   executes  commands  from  the file /etc/profile, if that file
>   exists.  After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile,
>   ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in  that order, and reads and executes
>   commands from the first one that exists and is readable.  The
>   --noprofile option may be  used  when  the shell is started to inhibit this behavior.

Comment: I was looking at the /etc/profile and it looks like a file link, there is no way of changing this path?